# GitLab CI image: alpine "apk: command not found" error

Tags: gitlab-ci, alpine-linux, python-black

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.aerian.fr/en/english-gitlab-ci-python-linting/) tutorial to enable formatting checks using [`black`](https://github.com/psf/black) in GitLab CI.

To make things simpler, I've transferred the code from `.lint-ci.yml` over to `.gitlab-ci.yml`. The tag of the shared runner that I'm using is `gitlab-ci`. I'm getting the following error when the pipeline gets run:

```
bash: line 80: apk: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Obviously, that's getting thrown for the `apk --no-cache add py3-pip python3-dev gcc linux-headers musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev git` line.

Here's the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
formatter:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - gitlab-ci
  image: alpine
  only:
    - branches
  before_script:
    - apk --no-cache add py3-pip python3-dev gcc linux-headers musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev git
    - pip install black
  script:
    - black . --check
  allow_failure: false
```

Can someone help me solve this issue?

As requested by @slauth, here's the full output of the job:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.6.1 (id1)
  on gitlab-ci -CzBAN4M
Using Shell executor...
Running on gitserver...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at id2 a
From http://gitserver....
Checking out id3 as gitlabci...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ apk --no-cache add py3-pip python3-dev gcc linux-headers musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev git
bash: line 80: apk: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com or a self-hosted server? Maybe your runner is using an [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) that does not support the `image:` configuration, see [this compatibility chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/index.html#compatibility-chart).

Comment: @slauth I'm using a self-hosted server, but looking at multiple `.gitlab-ci.yml` files in other projects, I can see that the `image:` configuration pops up everywhere, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Could you post the complete output of the `formatter` job?

Comment: @slauth I've edited the question to include the full output of the `formatter` job.

Comment: Notice the "Using Shell executor..." line. Maybe there are other runners available?

Comment: Thank you, changing the `gitlab-ci` tag to `docker` fixed the issue. :) I wanted to try that hours ago, but since there are multiple runners that use the tag `docker`, I wasn't sure what would happen if I used that tag.  Please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your runner is using the "Shell" executor which does not support the `image:` configuration, see this [compatibility chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/index.html#compatibility-chart).